# Jenkins service crashed after running a job. I had to restart the service and try again

Tags: jenkins, katalon-studio

I tried to execute katalon exe with a list of arguments. The job was executed successfully but service stops after that. Restarting also not works. I had to stop the jenkins server and run .war file again.

Comment: Hi Chella, did you have the issue resoloved? Could you share the solution for that?